# Behavior of distances and areas when Plate Carreé projection is applied to ellipsoid reference coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, area

*Disclaimer*: I am a Data Scientist, so bear with me regarding GIS knowledge.

I am working with a raster dataset that is Plate-Carrée projected using EPSG:4326 as a CRS.
Pixels are rendered via an affine transformation from the projected geographical coordinates.

Is it correct, that if the CRS were spherical, areas of pixels would not be skewed because the squishiness of distances between lines of longitude that happens, in reality, is symmetrical compared to the extension thereof created by the Plate-Carrée projection?

Further, it follows that for the given CRS which is ellipsoid, pixels' area will be increasingly skewed with increasing distance from the equator?

If that is true, how can I calculate the change in an area that happens?

I would like to know if the squishing distances between lines of longitude get outpaced by the extension of these via the Plate-Carée projection.

[Measurement Data Processing](https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/jpss/documents/UserGuides/Vegetation_Health_EUM.pdf)

Comment: If you use a GIS tool with geodetic distance and area support, then you don't need to work this out on your own.

Comment: I can't deal with it because it possibly impacts the scientific data-preprocessing of the dataset I use (STAR AVHRR VHP). Just want to know so I can report it in my work that this is a potential source of bias. It is not well-documented by the creators.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any spatial analysis in Plate Carrée, so this isn't really an issue. Project into something appropriate, and do your bias analysis there.

Comment: If the resolution of the remote sensing instrument that is used for the creation of the data set is at its highest for 2,5km x 6km, it will lead to inaccuracies, if a real pixel defined by lat/lon is smaller than this resolution. This has nothing to do with my analysis. I am questioning the measurement process.

Comment: Yes, of course a global geographic dataset will have inaccuracies. If your analysis has anything to do with measurement, it has *everything* to do with analysis.

Comment: I appreciate your advice regarding not doing analysis in Plate-Carrée. Let's put my analysis to the side and focus on the data process. 

A satellite measures light reflections with a certain resolution. Thus the end product should in no case be of higher resolution than the instrument is capable of providing. In the product description, the raster grid is defined by an affine transformation from coordinates in Plate-Carrée. It is statically defined as a degree value that resembles 4km2. What does the real area (which is captured by the measurement tool) look like with increasing latitude?

Comment: Sensors don't use Plate Carrée. And I doubt anyone really thinks that DD pixels have other than variable size.

Comment: When the measurement, which has a certain resolution is projected into Plate-Carrée during the data processing (mapping from coordinates to pixels), I was wondering about the effects of the skewed real sizes of the pixels in the projection of the output file. Is it clear now?

Comment: Frank Canters has published on this topic.

Comment: For equidistant cylindrical (plate carree) and standard parallel = 0, there's no north-south distortion, but east-west distortion is 1/cos(latitude).

Comment: Can you point me to the publication you are referring to please?
Furthermore, no north-south distortion with respect to what?
The latitudes stay the same, yes, but the distance in meters in the projection will certainly deviate from the distance observed on theactual surface of the earth, right? Thanks for your reply :)